# Subset pandas dataframe with lists

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I would like to subset my dataframe based on a couple of lists of variables, that is:

```
 list1=[var1,var2,var3]
 list2=[var4,var5,var6]

 data_final = data[list1,list2]
```

which produced this error:

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If I provide a single list, everything works fine:

```
 data_final = data[list1]
```

Below is a min-example:

```
dict1 = [{'var0': 0, 'var1': 1, 'var2': 2},
     {'var0': 0, 'var1': 2, 'var2': 4},
    {'var0': 1, 'var1': 5, 'var2': 8},
    {'var0': 1, 'var1': 15, 'var2': 12},]
 df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['s1', 's2','s3','s4'])

  list1=['var0']
  list2=['var1','var2']
```

These two commands work fine:

```
  df[list1]
  df[list2]
```

But this one produces the above mentioned error:

```
  df[list1,list2]
```

Comment: Show a complete example.

Comment: I have added an example to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the output you're expecting?

```
df[list1 + list2]
Out[106]: 
    var0  var1  var2
s1     0     1     2
s2     0     2     4
s3     1     5     8
s4     1    15    12
```

Comment: Yeah!!! This is awesome, thank you so much!! Who would have guessed that the answer was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your column names in one list not as list of lists:

```
data_final= data[[var1,var2,var3],[var4,var5,var6]]
```

From docs:

You can pass a list of columns to [] to select columns in that order. If a column is not contained in the DataFrame, an exception will be raised. Multiple columns can also be set in this manner

Comment: Thank you Neeraj. I actually did that until now, but I was hoping there is a way to use a list of lists, because my list of variables gets very long and the code gets very messy.

Answer (score 2):

To load any number of list into a dataframe in row (as long as the length of the lists are equal) you would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [10,20,30]
col_name = ['c1','c2','c3']
row_name = ['r1','r2']
pd.DataFrame([l1,l2],columns=col_name, index=row_name)

    c1  c2  c3
r1   1   2   3
r2  10  20  30
```

To load any number of lists into a dataframe in columns you would have to zip the list together like so:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [10,20,30]
col_name = ['c1','c2']
row_name = ['r1','r2','r3']
zipped_list = list(zip(l1,l2))

import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(zipped_list,columns=col_name,index=row_name)

    c1  c2
r1   1  10
r2   2  20
r3   3  30
```

Hope that helps, py-on!

Comment: Also very nice solution. Thank you for the elaborate explanation, this is good to know, this is going into my personal cheat sheet, should come in handy at some point.